# Flask - Forms - Blueprint

Tags: python, flask

In most simple cases I would make the following form in a html file like this:

```
<form action="/do_this" method ="POST">
```

and the action would carry out whatever that function did within the app.py file.

I'm now deep within a blueprint and I just want to set that form action in a simple way like the above but I can't figure out how to reference a certain .py file and then a function within it.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`url_for()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for).
In this case you would do:

```
  <form action="{{ url_for('your_blueprint.do_this') }}" method="POST">
```

The step which is of interest for me in the blueprint setup is the final line in this example:

```
from flask import Flask
from yourapplication.your_blueprint import your_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(your_blueprint) # hook your blueprint to your app
```

where Flask is instructed where to find your blueprint's functions.

---

Not relevant to this particular question, but something I just now learned is that if you're in the blueprint to which the action will go you can prefix the URL with `.` as a shortcut, e.g.:

```
  <form action="{{ url_for('.do_this') }}" method="POST">
```

Comment: so in a simple case '/do this' is a route/function in the app.py file. I have multiple .py files in this folder. Won't I need to specify what .py file to go to and reference that route/function?

Comment: A purpose of the blueprint is so that Flask will know which .py file to go to. I added more explanation to the answer.

Comment: that makes sense.. now I'm avoiding the invalid server error and getting a "CSRF token missing or incorrect." I'm just going to sleep on this one lol

Comment: Haha. Ok. Come back tomorrow and ask another question about that CSRF token.